# Pydev and *.pyc Files

Tags: python, pydev, python-2.5

I am using Eclipse 4.2.1 with the pydev Plugin (version 2.7.1) for python development.
It seems that pydev has problems with precompiled python files (*.pyc files). I am using a package which is only provided with such precompiled files.

When importing a module, pydev shows "unresolved import" error. And also tool tips are not provided for such precompiled modules.

But the code can be executed without any errors.

Is there any way to "teach" pydev, how to deal with *.pyc files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a bug. There is similar tread at http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/forums/forum/293649/topic/4651083: