# Using PYC file instead of a PY

Tags: python

A rookie question here:

I have a PY code and compiled it to create a .pyc. I would want to use this pyc file instead of PY.

I am running the PY file using external program. When the PY exists in the folder everything works perfect. However when I remove the PY file and simply use the pyc I get error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:/data/test/tech.py'
```

Whereas I have a tech.pyc lying around in the same folder.Any ideas what could be the issue here?

Comment: Did you try to run it or import it? In any case how exactly did you do that?

Comment: @msvalkon I think you can, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913193/is-it-possible-to-import-a-compiled-python-file

Comment: Ah, I'll refphrase. You *can* import the `.pyc` but I cannot understand what the benefit could be. It think it should be made clear that unlike a compiled language in which a program can be compiled into an executable binary and distributed "without" any concern, python `.pyc` do not serve that purpose.

Comment: I moved a step ahead now but when using PYC i get this error:SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xf3' in file tech.pyc. When my PY works as expected why pyc is an issue?

Answer (score 7):

Normally, python is not compiled. The `.pyc` files are only a performance optimization that improve loading times.

Python is looking for the `.py` file because it always checks that first. If a `.pyc` file is newer than its corresponding `.py` file, it will then use the `.pyc` file. If the `.py` file is newer it will create a new `.pyc` file.