# How to decompile .pyc file to .py using Jython

Tags: java, python, jython, decompiler

I have a python component that works independently and runs as a windows service. A particular file of this python does a specific job which i need to invoke using my java class. Since it's a production environment, .py file is not provided. To invoke a method "run" from .py file i am using the below code:

```
PyInterpreter py = new PyInterpreter();

py.execfile("C:\\Users\\narendrar\\Desktop\\hello.py");

PyInstance hello = py.createClass("Hello", "None");
    hello.invoke("run");
```

I want to perform similar operation, but with a compiled python file.

Comment: I have changed the approach to invoke python scripts. I am no longer using PyInterpreter, and using Runtime class from java to executing script.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the jython documentation about [modules](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/ModulesPackages.html), a jython `import` isn't necessarily about *Java packages*.

In other words: you should be able to import/require python modules as well, making it possible to rely on your pyc files!

( remember: you can import pyc files, .py files only get pulled in if they are *newer* than the pyc - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913193/is-it-possible-to-import-a-compiled-python-file) )

Comment: To give you the context, i am using jython library in my java maven project which uses PythonInterpreter to create java bytecode from py files.